# How can I execute C# within Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In my VS Code editor, I have installed the C# extension, but I can not get Console environment working. I installed two extensions 1- C# Extensions IDE 2- C# Snippets

Answer (score 1):

First insure you have

1. Installed the .Net Core SDK
2. Installed the C# extensions.

Click on the explorer icon at the top of the left bar. Select File > Open Folder and select the folder you want to create the C# project in. Select View>Integrated Terminal to open the integrated terminal. In the terminal window type .net new console. This will create the program.cs file for your project and the csproj file.  You now have a project and a C# file.